# Consistent PS2 prompt in zsh when editing multiline input?

Tags: zsh, prompt, zshrc

When using `PS1='>>> '` and `PS2='... '`, entering a multi line command looks like

```
>>> for file in *.txt; do
...     echo "-- $file"
...     cat "$file"
... done
(Here goes the output)
```

When editing the command however, `PS2` is ignored and I am seeing.

```
>>> for file in *.txt; do
    echo "-- $file"
    cat "$file"
done
(Here goes the output)
```

Note how the output and the command are no longer clearly separated.

Is it possible to make this more consistent, i.e. for multi line editing to respect `PS2`?

Comment: The purpose of `PS2` is to indicate the shell requires more input to complete the current command, not to provide formatting for an already complete command.

Comment: @chepner Then `PS2` is the wrong tool. But what is the right tool?

Comment: I don't know that there *is* one available. Possibly `zle_highlight`, which lets you at least provide some highlighting of the input line (for example, make it bold or change its color). See `man zshzle` for details.

Comment: @kdb Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Comment: @MarlonRichert Viable workaround for some cases, but not really solving the question. Though in this case the answer might be "there is no solution"?

Answer (score 2):

> Note how the output and the command are no longer clearly separated.

If your concern is to clearly separate command and output, just put something like this in your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook preexec separate
separate () {
  # If command has more than 1 line, add empty line before output.
  [[ $3 == *$'\n'* ]] && 
      print
}
```

Note: The 3rd arg to each `preexec` hook function contains the full text that will be executed. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec

---

Alternatively, you can just always print something after each command. For example:

```bash
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook preexec separate
separate () {
  print 'vvv'
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$3`? Is it the third parameter to `separate()`? Why the third? `$1` is the first parameter after the scriptname which is `$0`.

Comment: Good question. I added an explanation to my answer. Have a look.